# MySQL Database Restore Error

Tags: mysql, command-line, import, restore

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear

at line 1

Am getting the error while using the following mysql statement.
mysql -u root -p******** < network.sql

MySQL Server version is 5.5.21

The content of network.sql file is

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'server')
    DROP DATABASE [server]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [server]  ON (NAME = N'server', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\server.mdf' , SIZE = 1, FILEGROWTH = 10%) LOG ON (NAME = N'server_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\server_log.LDF' , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'autoclose', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'bulkcopy', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'trunc. log', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'torn page detection', N'true'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'read only', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'dbo use', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'single', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'autoshrink', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'ANSI null default', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'recursive triggers', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'ANSI nulls', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'concat null yields null', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'cursor close on commit', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'default to local cursor', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'quoted identifier', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'ANSI warnings', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'auto create statistics', N'true'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'server', N'auto update statistics', N'true'
GO

use [server]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Connection]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Connection]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[NodeInformation]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[NodeInformation]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[pda]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[pda]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[possibledelay]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[possibledelay]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[possiblepath]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[possiblepath]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Connection] (
    [NodeName] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [Neighbour] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [Cost] [decimal](10, 0) NULL ,
    [Delay] [decimal](18, 0) NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NodeInformation] (
    [NodeName] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [PortNo] [int] NULL ,
    [SystemName] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL, 
                [Status] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[NodeId] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pda] (
    [path] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [cost] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [delay] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[node] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL  
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[possibledelay] (
    [destination] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [path] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [delay] [decimal](18, 0) NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[possiblepath] (
    [destination] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [path] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [cost] [decimal](10, 0) NULL ,
    [delay] [decimal](18, 0) NULL 

) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: is this mysql? i don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you're trying to restore looks like a T-SQL file for MSSQL. So it won't work for MySQL. Not as-is, at least.

Comment: could you please help me in restoring this database? Atleast describe me the tables inside.

Answer (score 0):

First guess is it is picking up a line feed or cr from the text file and blowing up on that.  If you can access the database from a windows box, try running the same command from query browser.  Alternatively if it is a linux box, you can open the file in a text editor with all characters turned on and see where the extraneous character is coming in.